# How access 2-D array which is a typedef

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, typedef

If i have the following code

```
typedef float a[5][2];
a x = {(40,30),(46,30),(56,30),(58,30),(60,30)};
```

This got successfully compiled. I'm having issues accessing the elements of the above array x.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<2;j++)
{
printf("\nx[%d][%d]=%f",i,j,*x[z++]);
}
}
```

Above code outputs

```
x[0][0]=30.000000
x[0][1]=30.000000
x[1][0]=30.000000
x[1][1]=0.000000
x[2][0]=0.000000
x[2][1]=0.000000
x[3][0]=0.000000
x[3][1]=0.000000
x[4][0]=-1.781255
x[4][1]=0.000000
```

Comment: Did you try the correct array indexing? What do you expect from the - uncommon - expression?

Comment: Sorry, for a question in comments. But what does the line a x = {(40,30),(46,30),(56,30),(58,30),(60,30)}; means? The "(" should be "{" !?!? How does that even compiles?

Comment: @Olaf yes I did try , but I'm getting errors, as it is an reference to array, how can we index 2-D for a pointer. So, I just tried to print the memory locations from start . anything else to be tried ?

Comment: If you did it right, it would not have generated an error. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. There is no `z` in the snippet shown.

Comment: You did initialize z, did you? And do what Enak said, it seems like you used the comma operator.

Comment: @Enak, You're right, I'd replace the ( with { and that solved the issue, thanks. And answer to your question is yes, it did compile.

Comment: Style nit - you have a leaky abstraction.  The typedef name `a` does not convey the "array-ness" of `x` at all, yet you use the subscript operator on `x`.  If you have to *know* that `x` has array type in order to use it correctly, then it's better to not hide that "array-ness" behind a typedef (same goes for pointers, structs, etc.).  Just declare `x` as `float x[5][2];`.  Use typedefs when you want to *hide* implementation details from whomever's using the type.

Comment: `*x[z++]` How exactly does this code make sense? Is there any reason why you can't write `x[z][0]` ... `z++`? Too readable? Too safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with warnings

> warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
>   [-Wunused-value]

Because

```
a x = {(40,30),(46,30),(56,30),(58,30),(60,30)};
```

and

```
a x = {30, 30, 30, 30, 30};
```

are the same.

What you want is

```
a x = {{40,30},{46,30},{56,30},{58,30},{60,30}};
```

(braces instead of parenthesis)

or better yet

```
a x = {{40.f,30.f},{46.f,30.f},{56.f,30.f},{58.f,30.f},{60.f,30.f}};
```

Comment: you're right and that solved the issue. Posting the complete
code, for others, ' #include <stdio.h>

typedef float a[5][2];
void main()
{
a x = {{40.0,30.0},{46.0,30.0},{56.0,30.0},{58.0,30.0},{60.0,30.0}};
static int i,j,z;

for(i = 0; i<5;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<2;j++)
  {
  printf("\nx[%d][%d]=%f",i,j,x[i][j]);
  }
}
printf("\n");
return ;
} '

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code, but I start with the most drastic.

## Invalid array subscripting

`*x[z++]` is the same as `x[z++][0]`. Assuming `z` is `0` at the start, you are accessing array elements `x[0][0]`, `x[1][0]`, `x[2][0]`, ... , `x[8][0]`, and  `x[9][0]`. You are accessing out of bounds, and thus getting *undefined behaviour*. Last 5 values printed are garbage.

Just use syntax `x[i][j]`.

## Wrong array initializer

`(40,30)` will expand to `30`, because you are not using correct braces. Code is not illegal, but it will not give the result you want. Your code is equal to:

```
a x = {{30, 30}, {30, 30}, {30, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}};
```

Correct initializer would look like this:

```
a x = {{40.0f, 30.0f}, {46.0f, 30.0f}, {56.0f, 30.0f}, {58.0f, 30.0f}, {60.0f, 30.0f}};
```

Note how I used suffix `.0f` to indicate that these are floats. It's not strictly necessary, but it's good practice to use correct types.

## Hiding array behind typedef

This is not error, but it's not good practice to hide pointers or arrays behind `typedef`. Arrays behave unusually in certain situations (such as array decaying into pointer), which can suprise programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare the object **x**, it works just like a normal, 2-D array. However, I believe that the last parameter of your call to **printf()** should have a 2-D array passed in. So instead of:

```
printf("\nx[%d][%d]=%f",i,j,*x[z++]);
```

The ***x[z++]** should be something like:

```
printf("\nx[%d][%d]=%f",i,j,x[i][j]);
```

It looks as if you were passing a 1-D array in as the last parameter. Remember, If **z** is a variable you declared, showing the declaration in the example is extremely valuable.